Prove whether two formulas are logically equivalent to each other
Going through the exercises in my textbook, I have been given formulas
$F = \exists x(B(x) \wedge C(y))$ and $G = \exists y(B(y) \wedge C(y))$ and asked to prove whether (1): $F \Rightarrow G$ and/or (2): $G \Rightarrow F$.
Intuitively, I think (2) is right and (1) is incorrect. I start the proof thus:
(1) $\not \models \exists x(B(x) \wedge C(y)) \rightarrow \exists y(B(y) \wedge C(y))$.
Proof:
Let $M$ be a model and $v$ an assignment. If $[[\exists x(B(x) \wedge C(y))]]^M =$ 0, we are done. So assume it is true.

$[[\exists x(B(x) \wedge C(y))]]^M_v = 1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $[[B(x) \wedge C(y)]]^M_{v[x\mapsto\underline{x}]} = 1$ for some $\underline{x} \in \underline{M}$.

This is the case iff $\underline{x} \in [[B]]^M_{v[x\mapsto\underline{x}]} = 1$ for some $\underline{x} \in \underline{M}$ and $v(y) = a \in [[C(y)]]^M$ for some $\underline{a} \in \underline{M}$.

But if $[[\exists y(B(y) \wedge C(y))]]^M_v = 1$, then

$[[(B(y) \wedge C(y))]]^M_v = 1$ iff $[[B(y)]]^M_{v[y\mapsto\underline{y}]} = 1$ and $[[B(y)]]^M_{v[y\mapsto\underline{y}]} = 1$ for some $\underline{y} \in \underline{M}$

But by (2) we do not have that $\underline{x} = v(y) = \underline{a}$, so there can be a valuation where $\underline{x} \neq \underline{a}$, contradicting 4.

Therefore, $F \not \Rightarrow G$.


My main question here is whether the step 5 is not only warranted, but formally well-explained, and how to make the proof more legible or correct (in case my reasoning is flawed).
PS:
The symbol $\Rightarrow$ is defined as:
For arbitrary FOL-formulae A,B:
$B \models A$ iff for every structure $M$: if $M \models B$ then $M \models A$. A is a logical consequence of B, written $B \Rightarrow A$ iff $\models B \rightarrow A$.
Additionally: $B \Rightarrow A$ reads: for all $M$: for all $v$: $M \models_{v} B \rightarrow A$.

Without further details, we have to say that the two are not equivalent: the RHS is a sentence (no free variables) while the LHS is not so. Consider e.g. an interpretation with  domain the naturals and B as Even and C as Odd: we have that the RHS says that there is a number that is both Even and Odd, that is false, while the LHS says that there is an Even number (that is True) and that an unspecified number x is Odd, that can be True or False according to the value assigned to x.

Even if F is not closed, can't we assume it is true for a given structure and variable assignment and reason from that? The symbol $\Rightarrow$ is defined as:
For arbitrary FOL-formulae A,B:
$B \models A$ iff for every structure $M$: if $M \models B$ then $M \models A$. A is a logical consequence of B, written $B \Rightarrow A$ iff $\models B \rightarrow A$.
Additionally: $B \Rightarrow A$ reads: for all $M$: for all $v$: $M \models_{v} B \rightarrow A$.

A reasonable approach is to define "logical equivalence" for formulas using variable assignment functions: formulas $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are log equiv iff for every structure $A$ for the language and every function $s : \text {Var } \to \text {Dom}(A)$ : $A$ satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$ iff $A$ satisfies $\psi$ with $s$.

(I had accidentally pressed Enter and my comment was therefore incomplete, I've edited it to include the definition of $\Rightarrow$, which I think coincides with what you've just written). Given this definition, is the proof in the OP correct?

you have a closed formula and another formula with a free variable, they are not equivalent

Again, given the definition of $\Rightarrow$, why can't I reason about logical consequence between sentences and open formulas?
